# What is the right way to store JavaScript source code in a json object?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to edit JavaScript in a textarea and store it back into a JavaScript object. For example I have this object:

```
var item1 =   {
    'id' : 1,
    'title':'title',
    'sourcecode' : "alert('hallo')"
  };
```

If I would change the content to `alert("hallo")` or a even more complex example does this break my object?

I would think there is some escape function like this https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape. But it is marked as deprecated.

So if this is deprecated what would be the right way for storing complex JavaScript code into a JavaScript object?

Should I use stringify ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON
>   string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is
>   specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a
>   replacer array is specified.

This does not read like there is an automated escape build in.

Comment: `"alert('hallo')"` is just a string. You would escape it, like any other string, *before* you pass it to `JSON.stringify`, e.g. `"alert(\"hallo\")"`. Worth noting that it doesn't actually need escaping as-is, because it's using single quotes

Comment: Yes its a really simple example, of cause I would like to store more complex code with double and single qoutes mixed. So you mean stringify would be the right way ?

Comment: That's fine. The point is, the *source* does the escaping. Wherever you *create* `item1` and set the `sourcecode` property. Yes, `JSON.stringify` will create a JSON string representation of that object

Comment: Any javascript that you store will be as RGraham says "just" a string, you could maybe save every individual line in an array if you want to check it line by line or just improve readilibity while debugging. In terms of memory and access efficiency though you could probably not do better than a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to send the data to a server, I'd say you should `encodeURI` your sourceCode, and then JSON.stringify the entire object. When retreiving data from the server, you should `decodeURI` the sourceCode